# Access: finding the corresponding value of maximum value

Tags: ms-access, correlated-subquery

I have a database in which I perform an audit on a set of required documents, for several locations of those documents.

So I have a table named Locations and a table named Documents, which are correlated through a 2 x 2 relationship.

Every document can have multiple versions. In my query, I want to see only the most recent version of each document, so the max(Id).

Now, every version can be 'audited' (checked) multiple times, for example 2 times each year. Each Audit/check is stored in a record, and I want to show only the most recent audit for each document, so Max(ID).

This is my Selection Query:

```
SELECT [~Locations].Location, [+DocuProperties].Category, [~Documents].[Document name], Max([DocuVersion].Id) AS MaxDocuID, Max([Audit].Id) AS MaxAuditID, [Audit].Conclusion
FROM ([~Documents] INNER JOIN ([~Locations] INNER JOIN ([+DocuLocation] INNER JOIN [+DocuProperties] ON [+DocuLocation].Id = [+DocuProperties].DocuLocation) ON [~Locations].Id = [+DocuLocation].Location) ON [~Locations].Id = [+DocuLocation].DocuName) INNER JOIN (DocuVersion INNER JOIN 2Audit ON [DocuVersion].Id = [Audit].DocuVersion) ON [+DocuProperties].Id = [DocuVersion].DocuLocation
GROUP BY [~Locations].Location, [+Docuproperties].Category, [~Documents].[Document name], [Audit].Conclusion
```

However: I do not wish to Group on Audit Conclusion, I wish to show the Audit conclusion that corresponds to the Max(Id) of that Audit.
So for every most recent Audit, I want to show the Conclusion. This conclusion I want to show for each Document, grouped byCategory and grouped byLocation.

I know I need to build a nested subquery of some form, but I just can't get any code to work.

I hope anybody can help.

Comment: Can you post few sample data with field name (column heading) and desired output result for better understanding?

Comment: You actually use symbols in your table naming? I recommend not using punctuation/symbols nor spaces in naming convention.

Comment: @June7 yes I know, I have been using this database for quite some time now, when I started I didn't have any SQL knowledge so I would have done in differently with that knowledge. However, maybe you know this answer, If I wish to change the names of any tables,  often the forms/reports based on that table are not working anymore and I have to manually change the name everywhere in the code.
Is there a way to bypass this?

Comment: No, there is not. Could use a 3rd party add-in to do find/replace. Regardless, making those changes will not be a simple effort. Guess you better just live with as is.

Comment: @harun24hr I eventually got something to work, by making a query and then a query based on that query:

Query1:
SELECT [+DocuProperties].Location, Max([+DocuProperties].Id) AS MaxOfId
FROM [+DocuLocation] INNER JOIN [+DocuTheaterNorm] ON [+DocuLocation].Id = [+DocuProperties].DocuLocation
GROUP BY [+DocuProperties].DocuLocation;

And using that MaxOfId as Input for the ID in the second Query. I dit this for three separate tables so the eventual code has become very long and complicated. 
It seems to work for now.

Answer (score -1):

The basic idea is like this:

Table 1
DocuProperties

Id  Location    Category
1       15      1
2   15      1
3   14      2
(every location can have multiple document properties a.k.a. objects)
Table2

DocuVersion

Id  DocuProperty    DocumentEndDate
1   1       01-01-2022
2   1       20-07-2023
3   2       31-07-2023 etc.
4   3       01-10-2023

(every DocuProperties can have multiple versions, I have to check If they are still valid, but also on some other criteria ).

Table 3
Audit

Id  DocuVersion Conclusion
1   1           Not Valid
2   1           Not Valid
3   2           Valid
4   4           Valid
(every version can be audited multiple times. Every audit can have a different conclusion)
Which I would like to translate into the following:

LASTAudit (a.k.a. the most recent audit of the most recent version of the most recent property)
Location    DocutPropertyId DocuVersionId       AuditId     Conclusion

15      2                     2                  2          Not Valid
14      3                     4                  4          Valid

The ID’s were easy to get right, as those were just Max(Id) functions. The problem was to get the Conclusion corresponding to that audit of that version of that object.